# Error #2007 when Trying to pass a single variable to Actionscript 3 with URLLoader

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash

i'm getting TypeError: Error #2007:Parameter text must be non-null when passing variables from php to actionscript,

```
  import flash.events.MouseEvent;
  import flash.net.URLRequest;
  import flash.net.URLLoader;
  import flash.events.Event;

 stop();

 btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, klik)
 function klik (e:MouseEvent):void
 {
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/GAME_FLASH/load.php");
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(req);
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, complete);
 }

 function complete(e:Event):void
 {
test.text = e.target.data.$a;    => i think this is where my problem lies i got error #2007
 }
```

In my php :

```
 <?php
 $conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

 $db=mysql_select_db("derbie",$conn);

 $query = "SELECT * FROM case"; 
 $result = mysql_query($query);
 $a=10;
 header('Content-Type: text/xml');
 echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>\n";
 echo "<sock>\n";
  echo "<item>" . $a . "</item>\n";
  echo "</sock>\n";
  $closeconn = mysql_close($conn);
  ?>
```

any kind of help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to open DevTools and check response from your php script. Probably this response is empty.
Also it's really useful to add error handler to loader.